# Continue reading file after catching exception

Tags: java, file, io, bufferedreader

Ive got a data.txt file which consist of the numbers 
12 45 345 500 45.67684 33

once readData method is executed it should only print the values which are integers and print element not valid for any other type then continue like this

readData("data.txt") will 
print out the following:
12 45 345 500 element not valid 33

My problem is that once the element not valid statement is printed my code does not go on to print 33 it just stops at 12 45 345 500 element not valid

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Ex7 {

    public static void readData(String nameFile){

       try{
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(nameFile));
        String line = br.readLine();
        int i = 0; 

         while((line != null)){
            try{
            String[] lines = line.split(" ");
            int[] result = new int[lines.length];
            result[i] = Integer.parseInt(lines[i]);

            if(result[i] ==(int)result[i]){
               System.out.print(result[i] + " ");
            }
            i++;
        }

       }
        }catch(NumberFormatException e){
            System.out.println("element not valid " );
         }catch(IOException e){
          System.out.println("IO error");
          System.exit(0);
        }
    }

    public static void main (String[] args){
        readData("data.txt");
    }
}
```

Comment: Your NumberFormatException is catched outside of the while-loop, I advise you to verify the brackets of the try-, while- and catch-statements.

Comment: your try catch is not valid, you have 2 try one is not closed. Also you should pick then numberformatexception in the while loop itself, if you dont want to make big change in the code.

Comment: Btw while((line != null)) this will never exit when you handle exceptions inside while, which you must.

Comment: If your indentation wasn't so haphazard, it would be straightforward to see which blocks were inside which other blocks

Comment: Thank you everyone, you have helped greatly. much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for your question is that you do not understand the flow of control that happens.

It is pretty simple: you have a loop that reads from a file. But your **catch** is outside of that loop. So, when something throws, and you "catch" outside of the loop, that loop is "over"; there is no way getting back.

So, immediate answer is: move the try/catch for the NumberFormatException ... to the **one** place where it actually can occur.:

```
try {
  result[i] = Integer.parseInt(lines[i]);
 } catch (NumberFormatException ...
```

But of course ... that directly leads to the next problem with your code: you are using an array to store your "valid" inputs ... arrays have a fixed size. How do you know in advance how many members will be valid? You don't. Thus: you have to change from using an array to a dynamic list, like ArrayList. Now you can just add "valid" lines. But well, that doesn't really matter anyway. Because your method is **not** returning the collected values. But if data isn't used; there is no point in collecting it in the first place.

And the answer beyond the code changes you have to make: turn back to the books; and **learn** how the constructs/concepts that you are using actually work. There is no point in blindly typing down try/catch, just because they show up somewhere, or because your IDE tells you that somehow need to do something about exceptions. Meaning: when you write down code ... make sure that you really really **understand** what this code is doing. You know, like that other statement `if (result[i] == (int) result[i])` ... that will always be true; and simply doesn't make any sense at all.

Comment: thanks so much for the feedback I understand now, I do see my mistakes and where I went wrong

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest not using Exception but a check if it is a number. Exceptions are slow and should be used only as a fallback. Check this link for more info about the numeric string or search google for other ways.
[Numeric](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/math/NumberUtils.html)

Answer (score 1):

Put the NumberFormatException inside the While should work.

```
public static void readData(String nameFile){

   try{
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(nameFile));
        String line = br.readLine();
        int i = 0; 

        while((line != null)){
            try{
                String[] lines = line.split(" ");
                int[] result = new int[lines.length];
                result[i] = Integer.parseInt(lines[i]);

                if(result[i] ==(int)result[i]){
                   System.out.print(result[i] + " ");
                }
                i++;
            }catch(NumberFormatException e){
                System.out.println("element not valid " );
            }
        }
    }catch(IOException e){
      System.out.println("IO error");
      System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the catch block catching the NumberFormatException inside the loop but also consider the answer given by @Христо Стайков.

Answer (score 0):

use the below code:

```
 public static void readData(String nameFile) {

            try {
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(nameFile));
                String line = br.readLine();
                String[] lines = line.split(" ");
                int[] result = new int[lines.length];
                for(int i=0;i<lines.length;i++){
                    try{
                    result[i] = Integer.parseInt(lines[i]);
                    if(result[i] ==(int)result[i]){
                           System.out.print(result[i] + " ");
                    }
                    }catch(NumberFormatException nfe){
                        System.out.println("Number Invalid");
                    }
                }
            }catch(Exception ex){
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
```